# hide a shipping method if there is not shipping class in cart

Tags: woocommerce

I have been looking all over for clues but what I have found so far does not work. I want to hide a shipping method if there are **no** items in the cart with a specific shipping class. i have found methods to hide if there is a class in cart and can't seem to tweak it to get it to work for me. Can anyone modify this so that the cart will hide local delivery if shipping class "Cannabis" is not in the cart?

```
// Hides other shipping methods if cannabis is in cart
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates',     'hide_shipping_method_when_shipping_class_product_is_in_cart', 10, 2);

function hide_shipping_method_when_shipping_class_product_is_in_cart($available_shipping_methods, $package)
{

    // Shipping class IDs that need the method removed

    $shipping_class_ids = array(
        31          
    );
    $shipping_services_to_hide = array(
        'wf_shipping_usps:D_PRIORITY_MAIL',
        'wf_shipping_usps:D_EXPRESS_MAIL',
        'wf_shipping_usps:flat_rate_box_priority'
    );
    $shipping_class_exists = false;
    foreach(WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values) {
        if (in_array($values['data']->get_shipping_class_id() , $shipping_class_ids)) {
            $shipping_class_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($shipping_class_exists) {
        foreach($shipping_services_to_hide as & $value) {
            unset($available_shipping_methods[$value]);
        }
    }

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code which will hide a shipping method if there are no items in the cart with a specific shipping class. 
For details, please [refer this article](http://www.xadapter.com/2016/06/16/woocommerce-hide-shipping-methods-if-items-of-specific-shipping-class-is-not-in-cart/).

```
// Hides other shipping methods if items of specific Shipping Class is NOT in cart
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates',     'xa_hide_shipping_method_when_shipping_class_product_is_in_cart', 10, 2);

function xa_hide_shipping_method_when_shipping_class_product_is_in_cart($available_shipping_methods, $package)
{

    // Shipping class IDs that need the method removed

    $shipping_class_ids = array(
        31          
    );
    $shipping_services_to_hide = array(
        'wf_shipping_usps:D_PRIORITY_MAIL',
        'wf_shipping_usps:D_EXPRESS_MAIL',
        'wf_shipping_usps:flat_rate_box_priority'
    );
    $shipping_class_exists = false;
    foreach(WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values) {
        if (in_array($values['data']->get_shipping_class_id() , $shipping_class_ids)) {
            $shipping_class_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Negation of shipping class exists.
    if (!$shipping_class_exists) {
        foreach($shipping_services_to_hide as & $value) {
            unset($available_shipping_methods[$value]);
        }
    }

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```